# Fixing error in java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to capture#1 of?

Tags: java, generics

My code declares a value variable of type Object:

`final Object value;`

This variable is then loaded with an object.

A generic collection variable is then declared and loaded:

`final Collection<?> c = (Collection<?>) argumentDefinition.getFieldValue();`

The collection variable is generic in both instances above, with brackets and a question mark that don't pass through in this text.

When I try to use the add method of the collection:

`c.add(value)`

I get the error message:

> java: incompatible types:java.lang.Object cannot be converted to capture #1 of ?

The add method is declared in Collection as:

`boolean add(E e);`

How can I fix the error? I think I understand what's going on - the compiler creates a placeholder for the generic type that Object isn't compatible with. I can't use a raw type for the collection because I'm trying to eliminate raw types in the code. Do I need to use a helper function, and if so how exactly? Thank you.

Comment: Please post some actual code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: "with brackets and a question mark that don't pass through in this text."  -  Format your text as `code`

Comment: `Collection<?>` means: a Collection of an unknown type. It could be a Collection<String>, or a Collection<Integer>, or a Collection<Banana>. You don't know. So clearly, you can't add a random Object to that collection: if the object is a String, and the collection is a Collection<Integer>, that would ruin its type-safety.

Comment: What does `argumentDefinition.getFieldValue()` return?  What type?

Comment: pathfinderelite - argumentDefinition.getFieldValue() returns and Object.

Comment: JB Nizet - The only thing that's ever added is a pure Object, and I think the collection is always used to hold objects, so I think its OK. The code works when the rawtype is used.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to tell what exactly your problem is without knowing what `argumentDefinition.getFieldValue()` returns, but a possible solution would be change your variable type from `Collection<?>` to `Collection<Object>`.

Comment: I was assuming we had to preserve the generic nature of the collection, but since only objects are ever added, this looks good, and the code works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace  ? with Object. i think it will work

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class KaviTemre {
    final Object value="kavi";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new KaviTemre().myMethod();
    }
    void myMethod()

    {
        Collection<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
        final Collection<Object> c = (Collection<Object>)obj;
        c.add(value);

        for(Object o:c)
            System.out.println(o.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - making the collection concrete with Object works. Since they used a raw type, I was assuming that they needed to preserve the generic, but I think this is OK

Answer (score -1):

just cast to E before -- this may solve the problem

```
boolean add(E (E)e);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should do the following:

```
((Collection<Object>)c).add(value);
```

Then the code will compile and run.